# Facebook API Video Upload - Video Successfully Uploaded but Not Appearing on Page

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a project that involves uploading videos to Facebook Pages using the Facebook API. I've followed the documentation and implemented the video upload process using Python and the requests library. The issue I'm facing is that although the code returns success, the uploaded video is not appearing on my Facebook Page.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import requests
import os
#token = ...
#page_id=...
# reading file length
with open("/kaggle/input/dd45a2/videoplayback.mp4" , "rb") as video:
    content = video.read()
    video_len = len(content)

response = requests.post(f"https://graph-video.facebook.com/v18.0/{page_id}/videos?upload_phase=start&file_size={video_len}&access_token={token}")
first_setp_json = response.json()

# file splited using split command : split -b 150000 /kaggle/input/dd45a2/videoplayback.mp4 hhh
files = os.listdir()
files = [f  for f in files if f.startswith("hhh")]
start = 0
for file in files:
    response = requests.post(f"https://graph-video.facebook.com/v18.0/{page_id}/videos?upload_phase=transfer&upload_session_id={first_setp_json['upload_session_id']}&start_offset={start}&access_token={token}" , files={"video_file_chunk":open(file , "rb")})
    json_out = response.json()
    print(json_out)
    start = json_out["start_offset"]

#finish
response = requests.post(f"https://graph-video.facebook.com/v18.0/100128828655557/videos?upload_phase=finish&upload_session_id={first_setp_json['upload_session_id']}&access_token={token}")
first_setp_json = response.json()
# returns {'success': True}
```

also the permissions :

```
publish_video
pages_manage_cta
pages_manage_instant_articles
pages_show_list
read_page_mailboxes
business_management
pages_messaging
pages_messaging_subscriptions
page_events
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_metadata
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_ads
pages_manage_posts
pages_manage_engagement
instagram_manage_events
```

i have tried asking the facebook community but no answer